# How to use Location with javascript and something more

Tags: javascript, header

i'm trying to back with the **javascript:window.history.go(-1);** and add the **?error=1** on sequence in header(Location), its like

> ```
>   header('Location: javascript:window.history.go(-1);?error=1');
> ```

but it doesn't work, its possible back and add something ahead?

Comment: What programming language the code you wrote in? There is no `header()` function in javascript

Comment: Easy one, it's JHP :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. `javascript:` URLs are not valid in `Location` headers, and you cannot mix in the `?error=1` that way.

Assuming that this is actually in PHP, not Javascript, a more appropriate way to do this would be to determine the URL of the previous page from the referer header, and work from there:

```
$referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
header("Location: $referer?error=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

header() is a PHP function, that you are trying to mix up with some javascript. I assume that you want to do this in Javascript...

You can use `document.referrer` to get the previous url, which works only if the user arrived on the page by clicking on a link though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer

Then use: `document.location.href`:

```
document.location.href = document.referrer + '?error=1'
```

If you want to use PHP you need to use the `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` variable which contains the last visited URL:

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] . "?error=1");
```